# I have a problem with an if-else statement

Tags: python, python-3.x

Whenever I run the following code, it always runs the else statement, not the if. It works perfectly when I don't have the or operator, but I need to use it. I don't know what to do!

```
print('What is your favourite Pokemon?')
FavPokemon = input()
if FavPokemon == ('Pikachu' or 'pikachu'):
    print('Me too!')
else:
    print('Cool! ' + FavPokemon + ' is a good Pokemon. My favourite is Pikachu though!')
```

Comment: Check the syntax of the or statement. Do you mean `if s == a or s == b`?

Answer (score 4):

The statement isn't working because `or` doesn't do what you think it does.  The expression `('Pikachu' or 'pikachu')` evaluates to a single string, `'Pikachu'`.  The `==` then compares against that only.

What you probably want is:

```
if FavPokemon in ('Pikachu', 'pikachu'):
```

Answer (score 2):

```
print('What is your favourite Pokemon?')
 FavPokemon = input()
 if FavPokemon == 'Pikachu' or FavPokemon == 'pikachu':
     print('Me too!')
 else:
     print('Cool! ' + FavPokemon + ' is a good Pokemon. My favourite is Pikachu though!')
```

Is what your code needs to be. Your if statement needs to be changed. The expression before, `If x == (a or b)` will always evaluate to true. You were not checking if the `FavPokemon` variable was actually `Pikachu` or `pikachu`, you were checking is the condition `(a or b`) is true, which in that syntax, it is always true.

See https://www.w3schools.com/python/python_conditions.asp

Answer (score 1):

Programming languages are not natural languages and have different (and much stricter) grammars.

In natural languages, we all understand that "if a is equal to b or c" actually means "if a is equal to a or a is equal to b", but in programming language the formaly similar statement "if a == b or c" is parsed "if (expression) == (other expression)". Then each expression is evaluated (replaced with it's current final value) and only then the equality test is done. So

```
if a == b or c:
```

is really:

```
d = b or c
if a == d:
```

Now the expression `b or c` returns the first of `b` or `c` which has a true value. Since in Python a non-empty string as a true value, your code:

```
if FavPokemon == ('Pikachu' or 'pikachu'):
```

is really:

```
name = ('Pikachu' or 'pikachu')
if FavPokemon == name:
```

and since `'Pikachu'` is a non empty strings, this ends up as:

```
name = 'Pikachu'
if FavPokemon == name:
```

or more simply:

```
if FavPokemon == 'Pikachu':
```

The general rule is that if you want to test against multiple conditions, you have to write it explicitely, ie:

```
if a == b or a == c:
```

or

```
if a == b and x != y:
```

etc

Now if you want to test whether one object (string or whatever) is part of a collection of objects (tuple, list, etc), you can use the `in` operator:

```
a = 5
if a in (4, 5, 6):
    # ...
```

But in your case, since what you want is to test against the capitalized or uncapitalized version of the same word, you could instead transform the user's input (`FavPokemon`) in a "normalized" version and test against the "normalized" version of your string, ie instead of:

```
if FavPokemon in ('Pikachu', 'pikachu'):
```

you could write:

```
 FavPokemon = FavPokemon.lower()
 if FavPokemon == 'pikachu':
```

Note that this will be a bit less strict than the `in` version as it will accept "pIkachU" or "PIKACHU" or just any combination of upper/lowercase - but for your use case that's usually what's expected.

Answer (score 0):

**Working Code:**

```
print('What is your favourite Pokemon?')
FavPokemon = input()
if (FavPokemon == 'Pikachu' or FavPokemon == 'pikachu'):
    print('Me too!')
else:
    print('Cool! ' + FavPokemon + ' is a good Pokemon. My favourite is Pikachu though!')
```

**Useful Links**
[python-or-operator/](https://realpython.com/python-or-operator/)

Answer (score -3):

***EXPLANATION OF YOUR MISTAKE***

You have done a little syntax mistake in writing the if statement. You have written

`if FavPokemon == ('Pikachu' or 'pikachu'):`

Here u have kept `'Pikachu' or 'pikachu'` within parenthesis and checked **`FavPokemon`** outside that parenthesis with that `==` assignment operator sign.Doing these causes an error as it is unable to check with the condition.

***CORRECT CODE***

Correct code will be if you put the whole `FavPokemon == 'Pikachu' or FavPokemon =='pikachu'`into a parenthesis.This way it checks that whether **`FavPokemon`** is `"Pikachu"` or **`FavPokemon`** is `"pikachu"` and gives you the correct result.

The correct code will be:

```
print('What is your favourite Pokemon?')
FavPokemon = input()
if (FavPokemon == 'Pikachu' or FavPokemon =='pikachu'):
print('Me too!')
else:
print('Cool! ' + FavPokemon + ' is a good Pokemon. My favourite is Pikachu though!')
```

Comment: This isn't right either. The expression is equivalent to `((FavPokemon == 'Pikachu') or 'pikachu')` which will *always* be true - see https://docs.python.org/3/reference/expressions.html#operator-precedence.

Comment: yess sorry there was a silly mistake i did at the beginning. I edited the code again. Thanks for telling me.